# Linear transformations and finding the identity transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S:R^3 \rightarrow R^2$ and $T :R^2 \rightarrow R^3$ be linear transformations. Is it possible for $S\circ T$  to be the identity linear transformation? Is it possible for $T \circ S$ to be the identity linear transformation? In each case, if it is possible, give an example, and if it is not possible, explain why it is not.

I was able to identify that it will be possible for $S\circ T$ to be the identity linear transformation. I said that for $S\circ T$ to make sense the codomain of $T$ and domain of $S$ must match and in this case they do. Therefore the resulting composite transformation $S\circ T$ goes from the domain of $T$ to the codomain of $S$ and hence is $S\circ T: R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ so the result is standard matrix and we can use the identity matrices of a $2\times 3 $ matrix multiplied by $3\times 2$ matrix as an example which works out as the identity matrix of $2\times 2$ matrix. However I am unsure why $T\circ S$ would not be the identity transformation and unsure how the image and rank would come into the solution

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you know any connection between the rank of $T \circ S$ and the rank of $S$?

Comment: The rank will be at most 2? I think

Answer (score 1):

$S\circ T$ could be the identity.   Let $S:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^2$ be given by $S(x,y,z)=(x,y)$.  And let $T:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$ be given by $T(x,y)=(x,y,0)$. Then $S\circ T=I_{\mathbb R^2}$.

On the other hand, we can't get $T\circ S$ to be the identity of $\mathbb R^3$,  because the rank-nullity theorem tells us that the rank of $T:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3$ is at most $2=\operatorname{dim}\mathbb R^2$. But the dimension of the image equals the rank. This means $T$ can't be surjective.   Hence neither can $T\circ S$.

Answer (score 0):

If the transformation $T \circ S: R^3 \longrightarrow  R^3$ was the identity then $\dim(im(T \circ S)) = 3$. However since $ T :  R^2 \longrightarrow R^3$ is linear transformation it cannot be surjective. The dimension of it's image must be at most $2$. So we would get $dim(im(T \circ S)) = \dim(im(T|_{im(S)})) \leq 2$ which would be contradiction with $\dim(im(T \circ S)) = 3$ .